# sklearn-like imports / Hiding from public API

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

Suppose you have a Python package with a src-layout as follows:

```
package_folder
...
project.toml
/src
  /package
    __init__.py
    /models
      __init__.py
      _model_1.py
    ...
```

The file `_model_1.py` contains a class `Model1`. When `package` is installed, I'd like to import `Model1`as`from package.models import Model1`. For instance, in sklearn you import `MDS`as`from sklearn.manifold import MDS`although MDS is a class in`sklearn/manifold/_mds.py`. I specified the class to be imported with `__all__` as in [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/manifold/__init__.py):

```
## /src/package/models/__init__.py
from ._model_1 import Model1
__all__ = ["Model1"]
```

However, it does not work as expected, as the only way it works is by importing as `from package.moldels._model_1 import Model1`. I am trying to use only setuptools TOML. How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance!

This is the current `project.toml` I am using:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "package"
version = "0.1"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

and adding

```
[tool.setuptools]
package_dir = {"": "src"}
```

solved the problem. (why?)